# A book about an exiled princess, possibly 80's or early 90's

Tags: story-identification, magic

I'm looking for a book I read in the early 90's about a princess who is exiled after her family is murdered. I remember her family shared the throne with another family (her cousin I think). I believe her family had dark hair and complexion and the other family was golden or blonde.

She ends up being in a cavalry troupe for a noble or rich family but nobody knows who she is, except the younger son of that family. I think his name was Niall (maybe) and he was training to be a mage. She regains her throne at the end of the book and rules with her cousin. She also had an arranged marriage with a guy 10 or 15 years older than her, and she was able to use a little bit of magic herself.

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I last read it, but I'm almost positive this is *A Princess of the Chameln* by [Cherry Wilder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cherry_Wilder). It's the first book of the Rulers of Hylor series. The other books are:

- *Yorath the Wolf*
- *The Summer's King*
- *The Wanderer* (finished by Katya Reimann after Wilder's death)

The young woman's name is Aidris am Firn and her co-ruler is Sharn Am Zor.

Answer (score 2):

I similarly re-discovered Cherry Wilder's books recently.  My mother bought me a copy of *Yorath the Wolf* when I was 10 or so (the image of Yorath on the front made quite an impression on me, I remember it vividly) and I remember being intrigued by the book because it included a family tree at the front, but no map.

I'm reading the entire series now.  The writing is a bit dense and uneven ("Princess" has too many characters to count), and Wilder does a bit of exploration of voice and narrative mode.  "Princess" is told in a typical third person past tense, "Yorath" in first person past, "Summer's King" in first person present (which is particularly wierd).  Stylistically however I think it is reasonably strong.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SFF!  Your help is appreciated, but I think you should remove the final paragraph and post it as a new question or conduct your own research, as it's not really relevant to the question.

Comment: Okay, thanks for keeping me on track.